# I'm cold-crashing in a corny keg, in a fridge. I want to take some away in bottles in about 48 hours. Can I carbonate it at the same time?

Tags: carbonation, corny-keg, force-carbonation, cold-crash

So, i've done a few brews before (brew in a bag) but this is my first since getting a fridge and a corny keg. My beer has finished fermenting, and I've transferred it (minus the bottom gallon or so with all the crap) into a corny keg and put the keg in the fridge (at about 2.2C/36F) to cold crash it. (the main reason I did this is because the corny keg is the only thing that will fit in the fridge).

I'm going camping in about 48 hours and want to take some of the beer away with me in bottles, so ideally I would carbonate it first, in between now and then. What i'm wondering though, is if the carbonation will interfere with the cold-crashing. Would it be best to give it 24 hours without the CO2 and then turn it up to high (eg 35 psi) for the second 24 hours? Or can I just start carbonating now? (I already put a bit of CO2 in to flush the air out, then closed the CO2 regulator again, so no more will come in).

I do have a carbonation cap, so if I would get better results by not adding any CO2 at all in the next 48 hours, and then try to carbonate it in the bottles before leaving, then that's an option, but it's more hassle and will probably not be as carbonated as I'd like.

Regarding speeding up the clearing, I do have some gelatine (which has worked well before but i'd prefer to avoid, since I think it affects the flavour, and i'm trying to go as minimal as possible with this brew) and also some Bentonite (which I've not tried before), so there are some extra options there.

Grateful for any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would carbonate straight away, not wait 24H. Personally would not go above 2bar ~ 30 psi.

I don't use finings in home brew, cold crashing for 48H should be fine in such a small vessel.

Comment: thanks!  off i go to the beer shed.

Comment: BTW I will wait and see what happens in 48 hrs before any further comment but if the beer is carbonated and reasonably clear i'll mark it correct :)